# Configuring a customized build task in vs code for c++

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had a custom build system in sublime for C++ which takes input from one file and redirects the output to another.

My sublime build system is as follows :

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++14", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"selector":"source.cpp",
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path"
}
```

this helped in taking input from "inputf.in" file and print the output in "outputf.in" whenever i ran my program.
I want similar functionality in vs code but dont know how to configure build-task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a build task for a Node addon, you have to put it in `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npx node-pre-gyp build -j max",
      "problemMatcher": {
        "base": "$gcc",
        "fileLocation": [
          "relative",
          "${workspaceFolder}/build"
        ]
      },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can press Ctrl-Shift-P to bring the command palette and select configure build task.

The problem matcher allows VSCode to highlight the compiler errors in your editor.

The default build task is the one you launch with a hotkey.